# Numeric vs Factors & IF Statements

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a function for gender distribution. Is there a way to define a letter as something other than `as.factor`? I would like to operate `func(F)` instead of `func("F")`. Or should I go numeric: `func(0)`, `func(1)`, `func(2)`?

I also finished off the statement with an else that is designed to operate when left blank, but does not. If I whittle down the function to not include an IF statement a blank variable works fine:

```
genderDist <- function(){
    cat("Female:", sum(voterData$GENDER == "F"))
}
```

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Full Statement:

```
genderDist <- function(x){

  if (x == "F"){
    cat("Female:", sum(voterData$GENDER == "F"))
  }

  else if (x == "M"){
    cat("Male:", sum(voterData$GENDER == "M"))
  }

  else if(x == "U"){
    cat("Unknown:", sum(voterData$GENDER == ""))
  }

  else{
    cat("Female:", sum(voterData$GENDER == "F"))
    cat("Male:", sum(voterData$GENDER == "M"))
    cat("Unknown:", sum(voterData$GENDER == ""))
  }
```

Desired results:
genderDist(F) gives count of Females
genderDist(M) gives count of Males
genderDist(U) gives count of Unknown
genderDist() gives count for all the above

Comment: Do you know the `table` function? Try `table(voterData$GENDER)`.

Comment: @nicola yes, but the functions are not my issue, but rather the IF statement. the functions work fine.

Comment: Not much clear to me. Your function seems to calculate the occurrences of values in a vector, which is what `table` does, so I don't see a reason to reinvent the wheel. What is not working for you? Please, share examples of what you want to accomplish. How you are using your function? Do you receive errors or you just don't get your desired result?

Comment: @nicola desired results added to my question. I am using the cat() function because I want individual outputs instead of all levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities for coding gender, besides factor:
1. as **character**, not as factor. You will still have to call your function like `func("F")`.
2. You already thought of using **numeric**  yourself.   Disadvantage is that it may be unclear if 1 is male or female.
3. The best option IMHO would be to go **binary**. Name your column "male" and use `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NA` for unknown. The binary also works great in your if statement. Start with `if(is.na(male)) ... ; else if(male)`.

**EDIT**
But to achieve your desired outcome, the coding of gender is not the issue, I would take this approach:

```
#First, define variables Fe, Ma and Un
#WARNING: Do NOT USE 'F', as 'F' is an abbr. for 'FALSE'!!

Fe <- "F"
Ma <- "M"
Un <- "U"
#now define a lookup dataframe for convienience
LT <- data.frame(code = c(Fe,Ma,Un), name = c("Female","Male","Unknown"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# then define your function without an ifelse needed    
genderDist <- function(x){
    cat(LT[LT$code == x,"name"], sum(voterData$GENDER == x))
    }
```

Introduce some fake data:

```
voterData <- data.frame(GENDER= c("F","F","F","M","M","U"))
```

Then run function:

```
> genderDist(Fe)  
Female 3  
> genderDist(Ma)  
Male 2  
> genderDist(Un)  
Unknown 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but options 2 & 3 do not take care of the empty variable.

Comment: @Geppelt I added another approach to your problem, which I think is better. Let me know if it works?

Comment: Thanks! Works great!